# Forward page using Servlet Controller

Tags: jsp, servlets

servlet is like :

```
String rootJspPath = "/WEB-INF/jsp"
String page = request.getParameter("pageName")!=null?request.getParameter("pageName").toString();

String forwardPage = rootJspPath + "/" + page ;
request.getRequestDispatcher(forwardPage).forward(request, response);
```

in Web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ForwardServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>ForwardServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>common.ForwardServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ForwardServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/page</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

now call forward using servlet controller

```
<a href="/page/common/Welcome.jsp">click here</a>
```

please suggest convenient way to call this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ForwardServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>ForwardServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>common.ForwardServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ForwardServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/page/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

for your mapping, and

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(req.getPathInfo());

    dispatcher.forward(req,resp);
}
```

and then create the folder `common` and put `Welcome.jsp` in it.

Question wasn't the clearest: does that do what you want?

EDIT: Also, you should probably do some path verification on req.getPathInfo() to avoid people trying to directory hop using `..` characters, though for all I know the newer Java app servers catch that sort of badness automatically.

Comment: The `/page/*` URL pattern and `getPathInfo()` should already do it. I would however keep the JSP in `/WEB-INF` folder, otherwise one can still access it by directly entering their URL. As to hopping directories, this is totally not a concern since it just hops in the URL only not on the local disk file system.

Comment: Good to know: I figured it did that but couldn't really hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Based om what your servlet is doing:

```
<a href="/page/common/Welcome.jsp">click here</a>
```

should be

```
<a href="/page?pageName=common/Welcome.jsp">click here</a>
```

Which will look for Welcome.jsp in `WEB-INF/jsp/common` folder.